# Should I cross-post a question that hasn't been answered?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, cross-posting

I didn't get answer from my question for **EX:"[How to use chrome Plugins in Selenium WebDriver](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/16659/how-to-use-chrome-plugins-in-selenium-webdriver)" IN SQA**, So can i post same question on Stack Overflow. Please help me...
any how iam doing this for to get the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your question is not receiving sufficient attention on the original site then you should flag it and request that a moderator migrate it to a different site in preference to duplicating it.

Comment: how to flag the question? and what problem i face if i post in SO site?

Comment: @sameerjoshi Click "flag" underneath your post, select "in need of moderator attention" and ask them to migrate it. Be sure to tell the mod where you want it migrated **to**.

Comment: @sameerjoshi Having said that your question looks like a software request (what plugin do I use) so it is off-topic on [so]. Consider http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/  but please first read [What is required for a question to contain “enough information”](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information).